# Intermittent error with Running Access Queries through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a .xlsm file which compiles the entries from 5 Access database tables in a new spreadsheet then opens Access, and runs a couple queries to update the master table (I know, the architecture of the DBs is awful...) The problem arises (sometimes) with the following code,

```
Dim accessApp
Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.UserControl = True
accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("G:\Dir1\Dir2\Processing Database.accdb")
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "DeleteFTP", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

On the `OpenQuery` line I get a 'Runtime error 2486 you cannot carry out this action at the present time', is there some kind of code library I need to load or something to prevent this intermittent problem?

Comment: Are there other users accessing this DB?  Could the table possibly be locked due to something like this?

Comment: Perhaps...is there a way to determine if someone is in the Processing Database?

Comment: There is an .laccdb file in the same folder as the accdb file that you can read with a text editor.  The file should only be there if there is someone accessing the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try early binding the access application.

```
Dim accessApp As Access.Application
Set accessApp = New Access.Application
accessApp.UserControl = True
accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase("G:\Dir1\Dir2\Processing Database.accdb")
accessApp.DoCmd.SetWarnings False
accessApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "DeleteFTP", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

You might also want to try opening the database in exclusive mode.

```
accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase("G:\Dir1\Dir2\Processing Database.accdb", true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your *Processing Database.accdb* database includes a saved query named *DeleteFTP* and you want to execute that query.

If that is true, qualify `DoCmd` with the application object `accessApp` ...

```vb
accessApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "DeleteFTP", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

Note that if your Excel project does not include an Access reference, it won't recognize those Access constants, `acViewNormal` and `acEdit`. In that case, you can use the constants' values instead of their names:

```vb
accessApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "DeleteFTP", 0, 1
```

However I'm uncertain whether those suggestions are adequate because you said the problem is intermittent and it seems to me that your current code would always fail.  So there is something else involved which I don't understand.

Turning off `SetWarnings` suppresses information.  I don't know whether it's hiding clues in this case, but suggest you avoid it anyway.  You won't need it if you use the `DAO.Database.Execute` method with its `dbFailOnError` option to execute your delete query ...

```vb
'DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'DoCmd.OpenQuery "DeleteFTP", acViewNormal, acEdit
accessApp.CurrentDb.Execute "DeleteFTP", 128 ' dbFailOnError = 128
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll avoid  using 'SetWarnings' and look to include the accessApp. prefix.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using the Execute method on a saved query, if it's an action query rather than a request for data: accessApp.CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DeleteFTP").Execute  - you have options like the dbFailOnError flag, rolls back your deletions if there's an error, and a RecordsAffected property which allows you to capture the number of records you deleted.